# timing a sorting algorithm in python

Tags: python

What i am trying to do is to time a specific array using a sorting algorithm. What i have done so far seems to just time between two array increments; however I want it to continue adding time:

```
Example
n    time
500  0.0002
1000 0.0004
1500 0.0006
```

what i have is pretty much a same time interval:

```
n    time
500  0.00017
1000 0.00015
1500 0.00018
```

my part of the coding is

```
if sortfunction==1:
        array=x[increment-1:n:increment]
        for my in array:
            ff=sort_timehelp(x,quick_sort)
            print "%d\t %f" %(my, ff)
```

i think there is something wrong with the for loop function. Any help? thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [collecting data of timing sorting algorithms and patterns using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343822/collecting-data-of-timing-sorting-algorithms-and-patterns-using-python)

Comment: Don't post the same question twice. Improve the previous one, and give people time to answer.

Comment: actually i didn't know how to start it previously, but now i have a little idea of what to do, but i'm stuck, thats why i posted this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accumulate the time, start the *ff* variable at zero and the add the new timings on iteration of the loop:

```
if sortfunction==1:
        ff = 0.0
        array=x[increment-1:n:increment]
        for my in array:
            ff += sort_timehelp(x,quick_sort)
            print "%d\t %f" %(my, ff)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html).

Comment: actually the sort_timehelp(x,quick,sort) is a reference to the function of timing algorithm, it times it but it just does over the increment array; however it doesn't add it to previous time

Comment: @MW Ok, so store it in a variable and add the time to it after each iteration.